# How to run a powershell command in c#

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, powershell

So I am attempting to change the creation date of a text file in C#. The user will type in thr creation date of the file, it will then change the text files creation date to what the user inputted. Trouble is it keeps adding a ' for some reason resulting in an error message, it is calling on Powershell to accomplish this:

```
    public partial class Form6 : Form
    {
        public Form6()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string dir = textBox1.Text;

            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();



          ps.AddCommand("Get-ChildItem c:\\encryptedmessagehere.txt | % {$_.CreationTime = '"+ dir + "'}");

            ps.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

Trouble is, after the "'}");, it automatically adds another ', incorrecting the powershell command to change the date. Is there a way to stop it from adding the ' at the end?

The returned error is:

System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException
HResult=0x80131501
Message=The term 'Get - ChildItem  C:\encryptedmessagehere.txt | % {$_.CreationTime = '06/12/12 09:27:03 AM'} ' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Thank you.

Comment: `Get - ChildItem` <- this is your (first, if not only) problem, it should be `Get-ChildItem` without any spaces.

Comment: _"Is there a way to stop it from adding the ' at the end?"_ As far as I can see, that's just a delimiter inside the error message. Not a part of the actual command string.

Comment: Thanks I just tried that. The problem persists its adding the ' at the end, thanks.

Comment: Is it really necessary to use PowerShell for this? Is something stopping you using a  `FileInfo` object and using that to update the date?

Comment: What is the exact new error message? The extra ' is, like previously mentioned by Fildor just a delimiter for the error msg. The leading ' in `'Get-ChildItem` should raise the same concern otherwise.

Comment: The fact that I need to be input in the specific format, 09/28/07 10:00:07 PM as an example, the powershell command allows to do this easily. Thanks.

Comment: Message=The term 'Get-ChildItem c:\encryptedmessagehere.txt | % {$_.CreationTime = '09/12/12 09:26:13 AM'}' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. Oddly enough, when directly pasted into powershell this works perfectly.

Comment: If datetime formatting is the all you're using PowerShell for in this solution then you are making things way too complicated.

Comment: The `CreationTime` should be a real DateTime object, not some formatted (user input..) string

Comment: I am also getting that I can't convert string to long from the textbox when I use DateTime to change it, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

First, you need to use `Powershell.AddScript` method instead of `Powershell.AddCommand` method.

Second, you can try the following `Powershell` code to change the creation time of the file.

```
(Get-ChildItem d:\Test\new.txt).CreationTime =  '2020/09/23'
```

Finally, you can try the following c# code example to call powershell code in c#.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string datetime= textBox1.Text;
            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
            string script = string.Format("(Get-ChildItem d:\\New.txt).CreationTime = '{0}'", datetime);
            ps.AddScript(script);
            ps.Invoke();
            MessageBox.Show("Test");
        }
```

Comment: @KeiferBly, I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark my reply as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

In case anyone wants to know, you need to install the following NuGet packages to use PowerShell in C#:

- Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK
- System.Management.Automation

That's how I was able to get Jack J Jun's answer to work.