# Exit code 0 does not show the result and passing argument for ps1 file in c#

Tags: c#, powershell, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to run one of the feature of Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) via PowerShell in C# code. Even though, there is no error, I cannot see the result. In order to fix it, I have  read and implemented some suggestion in other stackoverflow questions but still i cannot see the result. Another question is that is it possible to pass argument for following code. In MS website, there is no example regarding passing argument. I hope there is a way to do it.

Code is here:

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddScript(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\username\Desktop\test.ps1"));
ps.Invoke();
```

The output of the Debug is :

```
The thread 0x4034 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4b34 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4f0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[18876] WSL_CS.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

But command prompt opened and closed very quickly.

In PowerShell, when I run the following code I can see the result.

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File test.ps1 5
```

Comment: Check `ps.HadErrors` and `ps.Streams.Error` after calling `Invoke()`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I have also tired these properties but command prompt has been closed very quick, the same situation is continuing unfortunately.

Comment: In your example when you run Powershell manually you add 5 as a parameter, where is the c# code to do that and what would happen if you ran the script in Powershell without that parameter, would it just exit?

Comment: @Tom yes it exited and Powershell turned into cmd prompt.

Comment: @mklement0 thank you so much. It seems working but I do not know how to pass an argument for this command. But i saw blue Powershell screen for a half second.

Comment: @Oğuz KAHRAMAN, you could refer to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64020356/11507778) I write to pass the argument for the command. I can use the command to change the CreationTime of a txt file.

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT thank you for the info. But i cannot see the Powershell and there is no error. My code is :
`PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
 int myVar = 2;
 string script = string.Format(@"-noexit -file C:\Users\username\Desktop\test.ps1 {0}", myVar);
 ps.AddScript(script);
 ps.Invoke();`

Comment: @OğuzKAHRAMAN, this usually implies that the script file cannot be found - please see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want **to launch a visible console window that executes a script file and stays open** (enters an interactive session after the script exits):

- Do NOT use the PowerShell SDK and its `PowerShell` .NET class: Its purpose is *programmatic* control of PowerShell commands, not visible, interactive execution.
- Instead, **use the general-purpose [`Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process) class to create a *child process* that launches the PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) in a visible console window (by default)**:

```cs
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(
  "powershell.exe",  // The Windows PowerShell CLI
  @"-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoExit -NoLogo -File C:\Users\username\Desktop\test.ps1 5"
).WaitForExit();
```

Note how the argument(s) to pass to the script file are specified after the script-file path (`5` in this example) - be sure to double-quote them as needed, such as when they contain embedded spaces.

Since everything after a `-File` (`-f`) is interpreted as the script-file path and the arguments to pass to the script, be sure to place these arguments *last* on the command line.

Alternatively, if you're creating a **.NET Core / .NET 5+** application, you may specify all arguments *individually*, in which case .NET takes care of any required double-quoting for you:

```cs
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(
  "powershell.exe",  // The Windows PowerShell CLI
   new string[] {
     "-ExecutionPolicy",
     "Bypass",
     "-NoExit",
     "-NoLogo",
     "-File",
     @"C:\Users\jdoe\Desktop\pg\pg.ps1",
     "5"  // Pass-through arguments.
   }
).WaitForExit();
```

**Pitfall**:

- `-NoExit` is *not* honored if the script file passed to `-File` *cannot be found*.

  - This contrasts with passing a piece of PowerShell source code to the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter, where `-NoExit` *is* honored, even if execution of the source code results in errors).
  - This discrepancy is arguably a *bug* and has been reported in [GitHub issue #10471](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10471).

The upshot is that if you launch the process not from an *existing* console window, a console window is created on demand, which *automatically closes shortly after*, namely after PowerShell has reported the error due to not finding the specified script file, making it all but impossible to see what happened.

The **workaround** is to use the **`-Command`** parameter instead, which keeps the window open unconditionally:

```cs
// Again, passing arguments individually is an option in .NET Core / .NET 5+
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(
  "powershell.exe",  // The Windows PowerShell CLI
  @"-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoExit -NoLogo -Command & C:\Users\username\Desktop\test.ps1 5"
).WaitForExit();
```

Note the use of `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-), to invoke the script (which isn't strictly necessary in *this case*, but generally is if the script-file path is *quoted* and/or contains variable references).

Also note that using **`-Command` changes how the pass-through arguments are interpreted**, which may or may not cause problems (not with a simple argument such as `5`); in short: after command-line parsing, during which *syntactic* (unescaped) `"` chars. are stripped, PowerShell *then* interprets the resulting arguments *as PowerShell source code*, subjecting them to an additional layer of interpretation - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67458726/45375) for more information.